# Display Bar chart values in the graph - ChartJS

Tags: chart.js, bar-chart

Can you please tell me how to display values in bars as below in bar chart. I am using ChartJS 3.6 version.

I have tried below code, it didn't work

```
const chartOptions = {
            responsive: false,
            plugins: {
                legend: {
                    display: false,
                },
                datalabels: {
                    display: true,
                    align: 'center',
                    anchor: 'center',
                },
            },
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the datalabels plugin to work you need to install it and register it:

Bundler:

```sh
npm install chartjs-plugin-datalabels
```

```js
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';
import ChartDataLabels from 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';

Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);
```

Script tag:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2"></script>
```

```js
Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);
```

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look at below runnable code and see how it can be done with [chartjs-plugin-datalabels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/).

```js
Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);
new Chart("barChart", {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Data',
      data: [5, 8, 24, 14],
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(124, 124, 255)',
      barPercentage: 0.5
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        color: 'white',
        font: {
          weight: 'bold'
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2"></script>
<canvas id="barChart"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `datalabels: "center"` and `anchor: "center"`

Comment: Thanks. I did. Still no luck.